# Can these rules be used to solve this logarithm?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I saw a video on logarithms saying if there is a limit where $x$ approaches $\pm\infty$ of some fraction, then we can solve by using these rules:

- If the largest power on the top and bottom are the same, then the limit is the division of the leading coefficients;
- If the largest power is on the bottom, then the limit is $0$;
- if the largest power is on the top then there is no horizontal asymptote.

For example, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4x+2}{2x+8}$ is $\frac{4}{2}$ or $2$ because the powers of $x$ are the same and we divide the leading coefficients.

Another one: $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{x+11}{x^3+16}$ is $0$ because the largest power is on the bottom.

My question: How do I compute the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{1/k}}$? This is particularly difficult for me because of the arbitrary variable $k$, and the fact that the largest power on top ($1$) is only greater than $\frac{1}{k}$ for all $k > 1$.

So there's a case where they can both be the same (where $k=1$ in which case we divide the leading coefficients which is 1), or the case where the largest power is on top ($k>1$), in which case there is no horizontal asymptote.

Comment: In general, $\log x$ is much smaller than $x^a$ for any $a>0$, so that limit is zero. The answer below suggests how to prove that.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But what if I choose to make $a$ small enough that $x^a$ is less than $\log x$?

Comment: It won't be smaller then $\log x$ for $x$ large enough. It will only be smaller for some $x$. $x^2+2$ is sometimes smaller than $x+10000000$, but $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x+100000000}{x^2+2} = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Use L'Hopital's Rule.${}$

I.e. 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{1/k}}=\lim_{x \to\infty}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\log x)}{\frac{d}{dx}(x^{1/k})}.$$

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to learn L'Hoptial's Rule now. :)

Comment: Great! Be very careful with it. For instance, you can't apply that rule to $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{\log x}.$$

Comment: Please read [here](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/sadun/F11/408N/L'Hopital.pdf) for a very nice proof of that rule.

Comment: I have a question about the baby rule: He says that rule isn't good enough to compute $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{x^2}$ because $g'(x)=0$. When he says $g'(x)=0$ I think he's referring to the derivative of the denominator. But isn't $2x$ the derivative of $x^2$, not $0$?

Comment: Notice that it says $g'(0)=0$. Indeed $g'(x)=2x$.

Comment: In "Proof of baby and macho theorems" where does $(x-a)$ come from in $[f(x) − f(a)]/(x − a)$?

Comment: You have $\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{t}}{\dfrac{b}{t}}$. Here you are dividing both in the denominator and numerator by the same quantity. This is like multiplying by 1.

Comment: Why does he use it in the first place?

Comment: Do you mean why is he multiplying by $1=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{(x-a)}}{\dfrac{1}{(x-a)}}$?

Comment: Why is $(x-a)$ being used if it's the same as multiplying by $1$?

Comment: Mathematicians always look to multiply by 1 to arrange and organize things. By the definition of derivative: $$g'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}.$$ This is equivalent to the limit shown in the proof. They multiply by 1 in that way ($(x-a)$) because they need to express the derivative.